# How to change nested property of an object using spread operator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

This is a clean version of the my situation:

```
const person1 = {
    name: "Person1 Name",
    hairColor: "Brown",

    backpack: {
        color: "Army-Green",
        content: [
            "item1",
            "item2",
            "..."
        ]
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to change only the **backpack color**

I already tried this code below but not success:

```
person = {...person1, backpack.color: "New backpack color"}};

person = {...person1, backpack: {...backpack, color: "New backpack color"}};

person = {...person1, backpack: {color: "New backpack color"}};

person = {...person1, backpack = {...backpack, color: "New backpack color"}};
```

Comment: Why not just `person1.backpack.color = 'New color'`?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Because that would also change `person1`

Comment: Ahh I see, you need a new object but with changed property. Then answers below show examples of how to do it properly. However, keep in mind that the spread operator is just a *shallow* copy of an object which means that nested objects are not deeply copied. Instead, only references to them are copied so there may be a situation where you change this nested object in the parent object copy and both `person1` and `person` will be affected by this change.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
const person2 = {...person1, backpack: {...person1.backpack, color: 'Red' }}
```

Answer (score 6):

You must spread the property first liek this below

```js
const person1 = {
    name: "Person1 Name",
    hairColor: "Brown",

    backpack: {
        color: "Army-Green",
        content: [
            "item1",
            "item2",
            "..."
        ]
    }
}

const person = {...person1, backpack : {...person1.backpack, color : "Red"}}

console.log(person)
```